# ExtJS image viewer

Tags: extjs, gallery, image-gallery

I have list of images in json format, and want to make an image gallery, but not with full features. Basically all I want is to display 4 pictures next to each other with 2 rows. And when the user clicks the thumbnail sees the large picture. How would I go about doing this.

Comment: i dono where to start, maybe give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to create an image gallery then everything you need is here:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/view/data-view.html